# Given an entity that can have a parent, or can stand on its own, what is the best way to represent it in a relational database

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

Lets assume we have to model the following entities:

1. Application :  Application submitted by users
2. Application Study: the study to determine if the Application  should be accepted
3. Consultation : A consultation with an external party as part of the Application Study.  Consultations with external parties could also be initiated independent of an Application Study.

So we have entity **Consultation** that can have parent **Application Study** or stand on its own. What is the best way to model this in a relational database?

I see 2 options:

1. have a nullable foreign key in **Consultation**  table referencing  **Application Study**
2. have 2 tables: **Application Study Consultation** with a non nullable **application_study_id** and another **Consultation**  table without any reference to application study.

Which is the best practice way?

EDITED:
There is a ONE-TO-MANY relationship between Application Studies and Consultations.  In other words, an application study can have multiple Consultations. Hense the foreign key.  In addition, an Application Study may or may not have a consulation.

Comment: The standard approach for designing database models is: start with a normalized model first, and de-normalize only when you really need it (for example, after you measured some performance bottleneck). Keeping that in mind, I am sure you answer your question by yourself.

Comment: @chrisl08: You need to be a bit more detailed about the business logic. Does every study have a consultation? Can a study have more than one consultation? Without this info it is impossible to answer.

Comment: It is possible that in this domain a Consultation may also relate to zero, one, or even more than one Application Study?

Comment: No, it is a 1-* relationship between studies and consultations

Answer (score 3):

- Option 2 is ruled out because you don't need a join table for 1:M relationships.
- The relationship between `APPLICATION_STUDY` and `CONSULTATION` is 0:M, not 1:M.
- Option 1 is the correct one. That's the usual way of modeling 0:M relationships: a nullable FK on the MANY side.

EDIT : Note that the 0 in *0:M* mean *0 or 1*, which is why you have a nullable FK on the many side.